# BigQuery's query filter by json type

Tags: google-bigquery

My database table like below.

| Row | Name | Info |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tom | `{"count":0, "error":[0,"failed",0]}` |
| 2 | Joe | `{"count":0, "error":["failed","failed","failed"]}` |
| 3 | Joe | `{"count":0, "error":[0,0,0]}` |
| 4 | Tom | `{"count":0, "error":["failed","failed",0]}` |

I hope filter data by "Info.error's array" in the following order.

1. all is 0
2. exclude all failed
3. at least one is 0

**result data**

| Row | Name | Info |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tom | `{"count":0, "error":[0,"failed",0]}` |
| 3 | Joe | `{"count":0, "error":[0,0,0]}` |
| 4 | Tom | `{"count":0, "error":["failed","failed",0]}` |

So, how should enter the SQL syntax?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please can you show your desired output to help in answering the question.

Comment: @JeremySavage
Result example added, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to simplify your rule set as rule 3 accounts for all scenarios you have listed.  Given your sample data try the following:

```
select *,
from sample_data
WHERE "0" in (SELECT * from UNNEST(JSON_VALUE_ARRAY(info, "$.error")))
```

It produces:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to find out the amount of a particular value in a json array you can use the following snippet:

```
  (SELECT
    COUNTIF(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(error) = "0")
  FROM
    UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(ex_table.Info, '$.error')) AS error ) count_zeros,
   
  (SELECT
    COUNTIF(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(error) = "failed")
  FROM
    UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(ex_table.Info, '$.error')) AS error ) count_failed
```

Using these two new variables, you can then create your actual filters.

1.

```
 WHERE
  count_zero = ARRAY_LENGTH(Info.error)
```

2. 

```
 WHERE 
  NOT count_failed = ARRAY_LENGTH(Info.error)
```

3. 

```
WHERE  
  count_zero > 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but source data of Info.error has multiple types.
That zero's type is number, so I can't use function "UNNEST".

Comment: and your data is already in Bigquery? Because that should not be possible to mix data types: See here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays
"In BigQuery, an array is an ordered list consisting of zero or more values of the same data type."

Comment: Data is already in BigQuery and data type is json from NOSQL.
So, I think it might be necessary to convert the type of zeros.
Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Hikaru,
I updated my answer to allow for your JSON fields. This should work now for your case too. Feel free to accept the answer if this works now for you!

Comment: Thanks for reply, I just try it later.